# What's my solutions if i brick my android phone?

Tags: unbricking

Are there any tricks (general or not) that I can use if I brick my Android phone? e.g.: when updating android..

Comment: This can vary a lot depending on what kind of phone you have.

Comment: This pretty subjective.  It usually depends on what you did to "brick" it and also varies by phone. For instance, there would be a difference in perma-bricking the device by flashing the wrong radio, vs flashing a rom and getting stuck in a boot loop or having issues flashing a recovery, etc.

Answer (score 3):

As you haven't mentioned your phone related information, I can share my view.

When your phone is not responding or bricked then you can use your phone PC Compassion or PC suite or whatever depends on what your phone model gave you.

I own Sony Ericsson Xperia Mini Pro. Sometime back while installing another ROM the phone bricked. I googled and read lots of articles to unbrick the phone.

Especially [XDA Forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/) helped me in unbricking the phone. Sony Ericsson has SEUS(Sony Ericsson Update Service).  Using this we can unbrick the Sony Ericsson phones. I am guessing the similar kind of set up is there in all the other phones also.

Comment: For samsung phones, Kies is the software for Unbricking

Answer (score 1):

I Hard Bricked my phone yesterday when I went to flash a custom ROM. I think I was trying to flash a ROM for the wrong model or something, not sure. Whatever, totally bricked. I had two options as I saw it:

### Option 1

Go to AT&T, play dumb, and see if they would give me a new phone. (it worked) **Since it was hard bricked, they could not even turn it on, they simply gave me a new one. My default 1-year warranty covered it.**

### Option 2

Send my phone into the [Mobile Techs](http://mobiletechvideos.mybigcommerce.com/). They came highly recommended and said they could unbrick a hard bricked Galaxy s3 (my specific model).